# Hypothetical animal material part 1

Tags: science-based, xenobiology

My animal was in another world . It had bones, teeth made of tungsten. It lives in shallow environment. What would the bite force of my tungsten reinforced animal teeth ( assuming it is plausible)?

Comment: Metallic tungsten? Or a compound akin to calcium in hydroxyapatite? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroxyapatite#:~:text=Hydroxyapatite%2C%20also%20called%20hydroxylapatite%20(HA,of%20the%20complex%20apatite%20group.

Comment: Metallic tungsten only

Comment: What is tungsten?

Comment: bite force has little to do with teeth and everything to do with muscle and jaw leverage, also what is a "shallow environment"

Comment: @Mmm Nmm   An animal with teeth made of tungsten?  Klono's tungsten teeth!  What a concept!

Comment: @MmmNmm I suggest for your next questions to detail more what you want for your creature, functionally speaking : big, small, mouth size and shape, what do they chew for a living...?  Here it's not that important since bite force is not really related to teeth material in general (apart from max force, and even then), but when there will be a relationship... We won't be able to answer you and the question will surely be closed :).

Comment: VTC Needs Details. Bite force is about muscles, not the material used to make the teeth. The material for the teeth only matters if the muscles are strong enough. Worse, though, is that any material can be shattered or crushed, so we need to also know the dimensions of the teeth. There's not enough information here to answer the question. But, more to the point, why do you need to know? Are you writing a story and expecting a materials scientist to take the time to prove your choice?

Comment: Ok i think that animals like megaladon and livytan and predator x have strong bite due to some material reinforcing their teeth and skull ? Is it true ?

Comment: @MmmNmm not really. At most their bones are structured in ways that help handling the stresses applied by the muscles. Even if I could magically turn my bones into tungsten I wouldn't be able to bite down harder. If anything, I might have more problems biting as tungsten is much heavier than my bones, and so just moving them around as I can now would require stronger muscles. The skeleton only needs to be more resistant than what it's biting down on, and must only be strong enough to handle the force of the muscle contractions so that biting down on something doesn't end in a shattered skull.

Answer (score 11):

Most of mammals' teeth are made of the same material, yet the bite force between a gorilla, a human, a mouse and a wolf varies wildly.

The same will be in your case: more than the material of which the teeth are made of, it depends on the use case for which those teeth have evolved: a carnivore will need more force than an herbivore.

Comment: *"a carnivore will need more force than an herbivore"* - unless the main diet of the herbivore consists of fruits with very hard shells it cracks open with its teeth.